# Core Data Entity rename

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I created a Core Data Entity called "MyObject". I then renamed the entity "ThatObject". But every time I create a NSManagedObject subclass, it still creates the .h/.m file as MyObject.

I take the "MyObject" files and just rename them to "ThatObject" and everything works, but its annoying to have to do that everytime i alter the entity attributes.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any versioning going on in your model?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When you are renaming the entity make sure you rename both `Name` and `Class` in the Data Model Inspector. In my project, if both are renamed the new auto-generated NSManagedObject subclasses are created with the new names.

[image: Dialog options to rename entity and class]

Comment: Ha! Under "Configurations", it lists the entities and the class. The class was still set to "MyObject". thanks!

Answer (score 13):

For future readers: Pay attention to the model version though, if your app is already published, updating the app may break the database schema on your users devices which results in a crash on launch. Core Data can automatically find a migration for this easy case, you can find more information on lightweight migrations [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html). You basically have to **set a renaming ID** so CD knows what got renamed to what even if skipping versions in between.