# Core Data attribute crawling as nil after renaming, even after I changed the name back

Tags: ios, core-data

I foolishly renamed some Core Data entity attributes and ran the app, then realised files I opened were crashing because they did not have the same attribute, so I changed the name back.

However, the attributes I renamed are still crawling as nil even after I changed the name back. Is there any easy fix to this without migration? I'm 99% sure renaming them was the problem as the non-renamed attributes aren't nil. Files made after this also don't throw this error when I load them.

If it helps, I have an unedited copy of the older file, is there any way to swap it out with the current one? Would that work?

Comment: Can you add error logs in your question?

Comment: The only error is "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". The other attributes I didn't rename don't throw this error

Comment: Add code where you are trying to fetch something from coredata.

Comment: The code is just arrayOfPages = openfile?.thearray as! [[UIBezierPath]] -- This code worked perfectly before I renamed then changed it back afterwards after running the app. It also works fine for new files.

Comment: I can only guess the issue, but have a look at this question's accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343819/core-data-entity-rename

Comment: This kinda sounds like you've installed an app with a different core data model over the top of an existing one. Did you remember to delete the original app from the device / simulator before you installed the new one? Have you changed the name of the attribute in both the model file and the Managed Object subclass?

Comment: Hi Ash, I don't think I have a managed object subclass? I think you might be right though about inadvertently changing the core data model as I just swapped the old file for the new one and I'm having the same issue. Worried I might have made an irreversible mistake here. If I update the app now, users won't be able to access files they made on previous versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to add migration, just remove and install the App.

But if you want to rename a property in already published App than you need to add lightweight migration.

Comment: This obviously deleted all my existing files  but I imported an old file and it worked! So won't be a problem for users. Thanks!