# Rename Core Data Entity without Loss of Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to rename a core data entity (not an attribute) using Swift, iOS 13.0+. I currently have a Core Data Entity named `Image`, but since SwiftUI has a reserved view under that name, I'm trying to rename the entity to `FileImage`.

I have followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15344070/5050285), but the data under that entity no longer remains on the device/mapped to the new entity. Any advice on how to rename a Core Data Entity without losing the data in that entity?

Comment: You need to set a renaming identifier for the entity. There's another answer on that question that covers this.

Comment: That still doesn't map the data currently on device to attach to the new entity name, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Posting here for anyone else who needs to rename CoreData Entities (in order to avoid conflicts with SwiftUI reserved names).

Change the name of the class name for the entity (under Class in the Data Model Inspector), but do not change the name of the Entity.

You'll now have to change the name of the entity used throughout the code to the new updated class name. (`FileImage` -> `Image`), but the CoreData will no longer be in conflict with the SwiftUI reserved keyword, while maintaining all your data.

[image]

Comment: Your question said you wanted to rename the entity, but your answer says to not rename the entity. That's why the other answers didn't help, because they were answering the question you asked instead of the question you needed an answer to.

Answer (score 6):

To rename CoreData entity:

1. Firstly set hash modifier and Renaming ID for your entity. Renaming ID should match the previous name of entity.

[image]

2. Select your .xcdatamodel in file navigator
3. Select "Add model version"
   [image]
4. Expand .xcdatamodel in file navigator:
   [image]
5. In file properties select a new version of .xcdatamodel:
   [image]
6. Then rename entity name and entity class name:
   [image]

After this you should rename your entity in all project.